# Running cTAKES using all cores available

Tags: computational-linguistics, software, ctakes

When running cTAKES on several text documents, is there any way to perform the processing using all the cores available?

E.g. it is taking around one day to process 2000 of my documents, as it is running on one core only by default, while I have a few cores idling around.

[image]